# MATLAB/Opencv: Converting 24 bit RGB image to 16 bit gray

Tags: matlab, image-processing, opencv

Do we have functions in OpenCV or in MATLAB to convert a 24 bit RGB image to 16 bit gray image. I tried CvConvertColor but it is of no use here.

(I can convert to grayscale using  cvtColor(src, bwsrc, CV_RGB2GRAY), more help needed, but I want to make it 16 bit from 32 bit.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I beleive there is the rgb2gray operator in matlab.

Here is a link to where you can read up on it from mathworks site:

http://www.mathworks.com/help/toolbox/images/ref/rgb2gray.html

This even tells you how to read in the image.  Most of the code you should need is there!!!

```
I = imread('board.tif');
J = rgb2gray(I);
figure, imshow(I), figure, imshow(J);
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried OpenCV's cvtcolor? I'm not sure which opencv version you are using but CvConvertColor no longer exists, you should probably set up the latest version.

cvtcolor:

http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/miscellaneous_transformations.html#cvtcolor

cvtColor itself has no further arguments, it is smart enough to check the bitness of source and destiny matrix. Opencv matrix objects, Mat objects, have a custom opencv type that holds their bitness, number of color channels and primitive type (details: http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/basic_structures.html#datatype ).

If you want to make sure if the resulting matrix is 16 bit, you can check the Mat type. If the matrixes are not in the bitness you require, opencv has other converter for that: http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/basic_structures.html?highlight=convert#mat-convertto

Comment: To convert to grayscale we could use cvtColor(src, bwsrc, CV_RGB2GRAY);
But I am not able to understand how the same function can be used for converting the pixel size from 32 bit (RGB) to 16 gray. Can you please write the corresponding arguments in cvtColor(src, bwsrc, ..... );